# How to make vscode detect .native.js and .web.js files in path intellisense?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, intellisense, react-native-web

I am working on a react native web project where file extensions can be .js, .native.js, .web.js, .android.js and .ios.js. I would like to know how i can make vscode detect files with such extension in path intellisense when i cmd+click on file path in import statement. If path resolve to multiple files it should show a picker to choose one.

Would like to know if i can configure it in vscode or any extension that can help. I have been searching it for long and can't find any solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This is now possible using the "moduleSuffixes" compiler option in your tsconfig.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "moduleSuffixes": [".ios", ".android", ".web", ""]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that this is [not currently possible](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/45715) in VSCode as TypeScript itself [does not support resolving modules with custom file extensions](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21926), like React Native's [platform-specific extensions](https://reactnative.dev/docs/platform-specific-code#platform-specific-extensions) (e.g. `*.native.js`).